# How to create new XML DOC with properties from an existing one?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML doc that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model>
    <id>_1</id>
    <nodes>
    <id>_2</id>
    <stencil>TASK</stencil>
    </nodes>
    <nodes>
    <id>_3</id>
    <stencil>TASK</stencil>
    </nodes>
</model>
```

I have to create another xml doc with the properties of nodes from the first doc. For the new doc I have to create a parent node 
called "definitions". Instead of the "model" node in the first doc I have to create a "process" node in the new doc that has an 
attribute "id" which value is the same as the content of the "id" child node of model. For each "nodes" node in the first doc 
if their "stencil" child node content equals "TASK" I create a "task" node in the new xml doc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions>
  <process id="_1">
    <task id="_2">
    </task>
    <task id="_3">
    </task>
  </process>
</definitions>
```

To achieve this I have created three classes Definitions, Process and Task :

```
public class Definitions {
         public Process extractProcess(Document simpleXml_doc) throws XPathExpressionException{
            Process p = new Process();
            p.setProcess("process");
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression xPathEx1 = xPath.compile("/model/id");
            Node n1 = (Node) xPathEx1.evaluate(simpleXml_doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            p.setIdProcess(n1.getTextContent());
            return p;
        }
}

public class Process {

     private String process;
     public String getProcess(){
         return process;
     }
     public void setProcess(String process){
         this.process = process;
     }
         private String idProcess;
            public String getIdProcess(){
                return idProcess;
            }
            public void setIdProcess(String idProcess){
                this.idProcess = idProcess;
            }


    public ArrayList<Task> extractTasks(Document firstXml_doc) throws XPathExpressionException{
        ArrayList<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathEx1 = xPath.compile("/model/nodes/stencil");
        NodeList nl1 = (NodeList) xPathEx1.evaluate(simpleXml_doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int index=0; index<nl1.getLength(); index++){
            if(nl1.item(index).getTextContent().equals("TASK")){
                Task t = new Task();
                t.setTask("task");
                XPathExpression xPathEx2 = xPath.compile("/model/nodes/id");
                NodeList nl2 = (NodeList) xPathEx2.evaluate(simpleXml_doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                t.setIdTask("_" + nl2.item(index).getTextContent());
                taskList.add(t);
            }
        }
        return taskList;
    }
}

public class Task {
    private String task; 
    public String getTask(){
        return task;
    }
    public void setTask(String task){
        this.task = task;
    }
    //do krijoj properties per atributet e elementit task
    private String idTask;
    private String nameTask;
    public String getIdTask(){
        return idTask;
    }
    public void setIdTask(String idTask){
        this.idTask = idTask;
    }
}
```

I just wanted to know if this is the correct way to define the respective classes.
Can anyone tell me any way to create and fill the nodes for the new doc using this 
classes?
I am used with DOM parser and I know how to create nodes and fill attribute values, 
but I have always done this job in a single class, not using different classes for the 
elements.

Comment: Given your definition of the problem, I'd handle this as pure procedural code: write something which walks the input document, pulling out the information you need, and outputting the resulting values as a new XML document, rather than building a full application-specific data model as you've started doing. Or just write an XSLT stylesheet that expresses the transformation you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea here, but perhaps you might want to think about using JAXB for this. It's cleaner and easier to understand. Using JAXB, you will unmarshal the given input XML file into Java object. Then, you create new Java object and marshal it back to XML string/file.

Here's how...

Let's assume you have the following:-

**INPUT XML STRUCTURE**

This is the XML structure you have and you put it in a file.

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model>
    <id>_1</id>
    <nodes>
        <id>_2</id>
        <stencil>TASK</stencil>
    </nodes>
    <nodes>
        <id>_3</id>
        <stencil>TASK</stencil>
    </nodes>
</model>
```

**CREATING JAVA OBJECTS FOR INPUT XML**

**Model Class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement
public class Model {
    @XmlElement
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private List<Node> nodes;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Model(String id, List<Node> nodes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Node> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }
}
```

**Node Class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Node {

    @XmlElement
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private String stencil;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(String id, String stencil) {
        this.id = id;
        this.stencil = stencil;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getStencil() {
        return stencil;
    }
}
```

**CREATING JAVA OBJECTS FOR OUTPUT XML**

**Definitions Class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Definitions {

    @XmlElement
    private Process process;

    public Definitions() {
    }

    public Definitions(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }

    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }
}
```

**Process Class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.util.List;

public class Process {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private List<Task> task;

    public Process() {
    }

    public Process(String id, List<Task> task) {
        this.id = id;
        this.task = task;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Task> getTask() {
        return task;
    }
}
```

**Task Class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Task {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    public Task() {
    }

    public Task(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**READING AND WRITING XML**

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        // initialize JAXB
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Model.class, Definitions.class);

        // Unmarshal input XML into Java object
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Model model = (Model) unmarshaller.unmarshal(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.xml"));

        // Map old Java object to new Java object
        List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        for (Node node : model.getNodes()) {
            tasks.add(new Task(node.getId()));
        }

        // Marshal new Java object into XML
        Definitions definitions = new Definitions(new Process(model.getId(), tasks));

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.marshal(definitions, sw);

        System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }
}
```

**Result**

When you execute the code above, you get the following XML string:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<definitions>
    <process id="_1">
        <task id="_2"/>
        <task id="_3"/>
    </process>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Really helpful and very well explained. Thank you